# How to implement a horizontal scroll which is controlled by bottom minus bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, controls

I have to implement a horizontal scroll list in flutter.I could do that and have included the code below(The code is still to be modified but the base of the code is good enough to put in the pictures and other such details)

But the problem is the minus bar below the horizontal scroll.I don't know what feature in flutter allows to do that.I search many things but other than radio boxes,check boxes, switches,etc I am not able to find any details of it.Please have a look at the screenshot of the app ,I have indicated the minus bar control in red.[Home screen,the minus bar indicated in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFYhK.png)

The code I have written:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black ,
       body: Container(
         margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),

         height: 500,
         child: ListView(
            // This next line does the trick.
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width:400 ,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 400.0,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 400.0,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),

            ],
          ),
       )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to look for is not `ListView` but `PageView` here is a small code sample to try in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/flutter) and see how you could make your layout.

Basically I am using a `PageController` to change the current page by taping on certain widgets.

**Code**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(body: MyWidget()),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final _items = [Colors.red, Colors.blue, Colors.yellow];
  final _pageController = PageController();
  
  int _currentPageNotifier = 0;

  final double _indicatorWidth = 30;

  Widget _buildPageView() {
    return PageView.builder(
      controller: _pageController,
      itemCount: _items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Center(
        child: FlutterLogo(
          colors: _items[index],
          size: 50,
        ),
      ),
      onPageChanged: (int index) =>
          setState(() => _currentPageNotifier = index),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildIndicator() {
    List<Widget> itemWidgets = [];
    for (int index = 0; index < _items.length; index++) {
      itemWidgets.add(GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => _pageController.animateToPage(
          index,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          curve: Curves.ease,
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: _currentPageNotifier == index
                ? Colors.green
                : Colors.grey,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
          width: _indicatorWidth,
          height: 8,
        ),
      ));
    }
    return Positioned(
      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - 50,
      left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 -
          _items.length * _indicatorWidth +
          _items.length * 10,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: itemWidgets,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildPageView(),
        _buildIndicator(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much,ur right I have to use a pageview builder .I did search for some pageview library from pub.dev but I was not getting the minus indicator properly.Thank you so much that you could solve this.If you don't mind you could explain about that 
_buildIndcator, a bit.Also can't I use a Scaffold and a Column in the body property instead of Stack??I tried but things are not coming the way I want.Anyhow thanks you so much, you made my day and I am marking your answer as correct.Cheers......

Comment: It is quite simple, the method _buildIndicator ensure that the correct number of buttons are created and that each navigate to the correct page. You should be able to use a Scaffold and a Column, I have used a Stack because on the image you have shared the indicators were overlayed on the image.